# How do I change the border color of image map that uses maphilight js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project with Image maps. I am using maphilight js for highlighting the image area. It works fine, but the border displayed in the tag area is red. Is there a way to change the color? I tried outline:0 but it did not work.

Link to my code - https://jsfiddle.net/5zL1ysvt/

Thanks.

```js
 $(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
  });
var myData = {
    "left-eye": {
        "title": "This point A",
        
        "description": "Lorem ipsum A dolor sin amet."
    },
    "mouth": {
        "title": "This point B",
       
        "description": "Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet."
    },
   
};

var areas         = document.getElementsByTagName('area'),
    bubble        = document.getElementById('myBubble'),
    bubbleContent = document.getElementById('myBubbleContent'),
    bubbleClose   = document.getElementById('myBubbleCloseButton');

// On click of an area, open popup
for(var i=0, l=areas.length; i<l; i++) {
  areas[i].addEventListener('click', openBubble, false);
}

// On click of close button, close popup
bubbleClose.addEventListener('click', closeBubble, false);

function openBubble() {
  var content = myData[this.id];
  bubbleContent.innerHTML = '<h3>' + content.title + '</h3>'
                          + '<img src="' + content.image + '" alt="" />'
                          + '<p>' + content.description + '</p>';
  bubble.style.top = (event.clientY + 1) + "px";                        
  bubble.style.left = (event.clientX + 1) + "px";                        
  bubble.className = 'shown';
}

function closeBubble() {
  bubble.className = '';
}

// Make the image map responsive
imageMapResize();
```

```css
#myWrapper{ position: relative; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#myImage{ display: block; }
#myBubble{  background: #fff; border: 1px solid #aaa; padding: .5rem 1rem; display: none; top: 1.5rem; left: 1.5rem; width: 15rem; cursor: pointer; }
#myBubble.shown{position: fixed; display: block;cursor: pointer; }
#myBubble img{ display: block; width: 100%;cursor: pointer; 
}
#myBubbleCloseButton{ position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; padding: .5rem; background: #eee; line-height: 1; cursor: pointer; }
#myBubbleCloseButton:hover{ background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer/master/js/imageMapResizer.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maphilight/1.4.0/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>

<div id="myWrapper">

   <img id="myImage" src="http://tinypic.com/images/goodbye.jpg" usemap="#myMap" alt="" class="map" />


 <map name="myMap" id="myMap">
  <area id="left-eye" class="map" coords="118,36,148,80" shape="rect" href="javascript:void(0);">
  <area id="mouth"  coords="121,84,198,118" shape="rect">
</map>

   <div id="myBubble">
      <div id="myBubbleContent"></div>
      <div id="myBubbleCloseButton">✕</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the data-maphilight to change the border.

```
data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff"}'
```

data-maphilight is placed in area.

```
<area id="mouth"  data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff"}' coords="121,84,198,118" shape="rect">
```

Comment: Thankyou, how do I change the highlight from transparent to light green color?

Comment: @newuser there are also fillColor and fillOpacity properties. check out the documentation for more info https://projects.davidlynch.org/maphilight/docs/